# Attempting to serialize the session as a JSON not converting types correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

[Serializing the Session using JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#serializing-session-using-json) specifies that I can create the following bean

```java
@Bean
RedisSerializer<Object> springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);
}
```

to make it serialize to JSON.  I do see the data being serialized (at least the initial data)

My data code is just a single field

```
@Data
public class MySessionData implements Serializable {
  private String email;
}
```

But it fails on calling this method

```java
  @PostMapping("/storeSessionData")
  public RedirectView storeSessionData(
      final String email, @SessionAttribute MySessionData sessionData) {

    sessionData.setEmail(email);
    return new RedirectView("/all");
  }
```

The error log message says

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'mvc.MySessionData'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'mvc.MySessionData': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Am I missing another step?

I do know that if I do this test

```
  @Test
  void convertMySessionData() {

    final Map<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    linkedHashMap.put("email", "abc");
    final var convert = conversionService.convert(linkedHashMap, MySessionData.class);
    assertThat(convert.getEmail()).isEqualTo("abc");
  }
```

I get a similar response

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [mvc.MySessionData]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at template.HttpRequestTest.convertMySessionData(HttpRequestTest.java:84)
...
```